# PHP search using BETWEEN not working

Tags: php, mysql

I create a two field that search between two entries. by using GET method.

```
<form name="search">
  <input name="to" id="to" type="text" />
  <input name="end" id="end" type="text" />
  <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="administrator";
$db_tb_name="customer_details";
$db_tb_usr_name="name";
$db_tb_npkgr_name="no_of_pkg";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$s_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['to']);
$m_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['end']);

$query_for_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
$db_tb_npkgr_name BETWEEN '%".$s_name."%' AND '%".$m_name."%'");

while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_usr_name], 0,160); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php } mysql_close(); }?>
</table>
```

In this code the output showing nothing, but when I use one field for search then it work properly.

here is the working code for single search. I use here LIKE operator.

```
<form name="search">
  <input name="to" id="to" type="text" />
  <input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" />
</form>
<table border="1">
  <tr>
    <td>Name</td>
  </tr>
<?php

if(isset($_GET['submit'])){

$db_host="localhost";
$db_username="root";
$db_password="";
$db_name="administrator";
$db_tb_name="customer_details";
$db_tb_usr_name="name";
$db_tb_npkgr_name="no_of_pkg";

mysql_connect("$db_host","$db_username","$db_password");
mysql_select_db("$db_name");

$s_name=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['to']);

$query_for_result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
$db_tb_npkgr_name LIKE '%".$s_name."%'");


while($data_fetch=mysql_fetch_array($query_for_result))
{
?>
  <tr>
    <td><?php echo substr($data_fetch[$db_tb_usr_name], 0,160); ?></td>
  </tr>
<?php }
mysql_close(); }?>
</table>
```

This code work great. But when I use BETWEEN then it shows nothing in output.
What is the wrong? What is the solution?

Thank you.

Comment: `BETWEEN` doesn't work like the `LIKE` command. You can't use the wildcard (`%`) characters. Also, obligatory sql injection warning.

Comment: Then what is the solution for this code?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#operator_between

Comment: SQL Injection warning not appropriate - OP has escaped the user input in the first snippet.

Comment: Try removing the wildcard characters.

Comment: Can you explain the semantic of your predicate? For me it seems a little ambiguous.

Comment: `SELECT * FROM $db_tb_name WHERE 
$db_tb_npkgr_name BETWEEN '".$s_name."' AND '".$m_name."'`

Comment: Solved... Thanks @Jonathan Kuhn.

Thanks all of you...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`BETWEEN` doesn't work like the `LIKE` command. You can't use the wildcard (`%`) characters. Try removing them.